# Why is my new ddev Drupal 10 project failing to start?

Tags: ddev

I have many ddev projects on my Mac. This is the first where I'm starting a new Drupal 10 project rather than upgrading a Drupal 9 site.

1. I clone the Pantheon repo
2. cd to the repo
3. composer install
4. ddev config

The config completes and says it's ready for ddev start, which seems like it's going to work but then fails seemingly complaining about the .ddev folder not existing, though it does.

```
ddev start
Starting sandbox... 
Network ddev-sandbox_default  Created 
Container ddev-sandbox-dba  Started 
Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/Users/me/Sites/sandbox/.ddev': mkdir /host_mnt/Users/me/Sites/sandbox/.ddev: no such file or directory 
Failed to start sandbox: ComposeCmd failed to run 'COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=ddev-sandbox docker-compose -f /Users/me/Sites/sandbox/.ddev/.ddev-docker-compose-full.yaml up --build -d', action='[up --build -d]', err='exit status 1', stdout='#1 [drud/ddev-dbserver-mariadb-10.4:v1.21.5-sandbox-built internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 transferring dockerfile: 612B done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [drud/ddev-webserver:v1.21.5-sandbox-built internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#2 transferring dockerfile: 976B 0.0s done
#2 DONE 0.0s

#3 [drud/ddev-dbserver-mariadb-10.4:v1.21.5-sandbox-built internal] load .dockerignore
#3 transferring context: 2B done
#3 DONE 0.0s

#4 [drud/ddev-webserver:v1.21.5-sandbox-built internal] load .dockerignore
#4 transferring context: 2B 0.0s done
#4 DONE 0.0s

#5 [drud/ddev-webserver:v1.21.5-sandbox-built internal] load metadata for docker.io/drud/ddev-webserver:v1.21.5
#5 DONE 0.0s

#6 [drud/ddev-dbserver-mariadb-10.4:v1.21.5-sandbox-built internal] load metadata for docker.io/drud/ddev-dbserver-mariadb-10.4:v1.21.5
#6 DONE 0.0s

#7 [drud/ddev-dbserver-mariadb-10.4:v1.21.5-sandbox-built 1/2] FROM docker.io/drud/ddev-dbserver-mariadb-10.4:v1.21.5
#7 DONE 0.0s

#8 [drud/ddev-dbserver-mariadb-10.4:v1.21.5-sandbox-built 2/2] RUN (groupadd --gid 20 "me" || groupadd "me" || true) && (useradd  -l -m -s "/bin/bash" --gid "me" --comment '' --uid 501 "me" || useradd  -l -m -s "/bin/bash" --gid "me" --comment '' "me" || useradd  -l -m -s "/bin/bash" --gid "20" --comment '' "me" || useradd -l -m -s "/bin/bash" --comment '' me )
#8 CACHED

#9 [drud/ddev-webserver:v1.21.5-sandbox-built 1/4] FROM docker.io/drud/ddev-webserver:v1.21.5
#9 DONE 0.0s

#10 [drud/ddev-webserver:v1.21.5-sandbox-built 2/4] RUN (groupadd --gid 20 "me" || groupadd "me" || true) && (useradd  -l -m -s "/bin/bash" --gid "me" --comment '' --uid 501 "me" || useradd  -l -m -s "/bin/bash" --gid "me" --comment '' "me" || useradd  -l -m -s "/bin/bash" --gid "20" --comment '' "me" || useradd -l -m -s "/bin/bash" --comment '' me )
#10 CACHED

#11 [drud/ddev-webserver:v1.21.5-sandbox-built 3/4] RUN export XDEBUG_MODE=off; composer self-update --stable || composer self-update --stable || true; composer self-update --2 || composer self-update --2 || true
#11 CACHED

#12 [drud/ddev-webserver:v1.21.5-sandbox-built 4/4] RUN mkdir -p /home/me && chown me /home/me && chmod 600 /home/me/.pgpass
#12 CACHED

#13 [drud/ddev-dbserver-mariadb-10.4:v1.21.5-sandbox-built] exporting to image
#13 exporting layers done
#13 writing image sha256:0cbebcfd096fe2fb424d18a06bc0ae2fb1eb6e4b7d5e974eb96cb7487bfb5716 done
#13 naming to docker.io/drud/ddev-webserver:v1.21.5-sandbox-built done
#13 writing image sha256:e0d9492258d3962e4106d43dc4feaed348beb313554d301306a3b63cb9a62809
#13 writing image sha256:e0d9492258d3962e4106d43dc4feaed348beb313554d301306a3b63cb9a62809 done
#13 naming to docker.io/drud/ddev-dbserver-mariadb-10.4:v1.21.5-sandbox-built done
#13 DONE 0.1s
', stderr='Network ddev-sandbox_default  Creating
Network ddev-sandbox_default  Created
Container ddev-sandbox-dba  Creating
Container ddev-sandbox-web  Creating
Container ddev-sandbox-db  Creating
Container ddev-sandbox-dba  Created
Container ddev-sandbox-web  Created
Container ddev-sandbox-db  Created
Container ddev-sandbox-db  Starting
Container ddev-sandbox-dba  Starting
Container ddev-sandbox-web  Starting
Container ddev-sandbox-dba  Started
Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/Users/me/Sites/sandbox/.ddev': mkdir /host_mnt/Users/me/Sites/sandbox/.ddev: no such file or directory'
```

==== ADDING OUTPUT FROM ddev debug test ====

```
ddev debug test
Running bash [-c /var/folders/7z/krwqzc0542s8szx09_0s1ktr0000gn/T/test_ddev.sh] 
======= Existing project config =========
These config files were loaded for project sandbox: [/Users/me/Sites/sandbox/.ddev/config.yaml]
name: sandbox
type: drupal10
docroot: web
php_version: 8.1
webserver_type: nginx-fpm
webimage: drud/ddev-webserver:v1.21.5
router_http_port: 80
router_https_port: 443
additional_hostnames: []
additional_fqdns: []
database: {mariadb 10.4}
mailhog_port: 8025
mailhog_https_port: 8026
phpmyadmin_port: 8036
phpmyadmin_https_port: 8037
project_tld: ddev.site
use_dns_when_possible: true
composer_version: 2
nodejs_version: 16
default_container_timeout: 120
======= Creating dummy project named  tryddevproject-12561 in ../tryddevproject-12561 =========
OS Information: Darwin Jeffs-MacBook-Pro.local 21.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.6.0: Mon Apr 24 21:11:17 PDT 2023; root:xnu-8020.240.18.701.5~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000 arm64
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 12.6.6
BuildVersion:   21G646
User information: uid=501(me) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),98(_lpadmin),701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),33(_appstore),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer),250(_analyticsusers),395(com.apple.access_ftp),398(com.apple.access_screensharing),399(com.apple.access_ssh),400(com.apple.access_remote_ae)
DDEV version:  ITEM             VALUE                                   
 DDEV version     v1.21.6                                 
 architecture     arm64                                   
 db               drud/ddev-dbserver-mariadb-10.4:v1.21.5 
 dba              phpmyadmin:5                            
 ddev-ssh-agent   drud/ddev-ssh-agent:v1.21.5             
 docker           20.10.22                                
 docker-compose   v2.15.1                                 
 docker-platform  docker-desktop                          
 mutagen          0.16.0                                  
 os               darwin                                  
 router           drud/ddev-router:v1.21.5                
 web              drud/ddev-webserver:v1.21.5             
PROXY settings: HTTP_PROXY='' HTTPS_PROXY='' http_proxy='' NO_PROXY=''
======= DDEV global info =========
Global configuration:
instrumentation-opt-in=true
omit-containers=[]
mutagen-enabled=false
nfs-mount-enabled=false
router-bind-all-interfaces=false
internet-detection-timeout-ms=3000
disable-http2=false
use-letsencrypt=false
letsencrypt-email=
table-style=default
simple-formatting=false
auto-restart-containers=false
use-hardened-images=false
fail-on-hook-fail=false
required-docker-compose-version=
use-docker-compose-from-path=false
project-tld=
xdebug-ide-location=
no-bind-mounts=false
use-traefik=false
wsl2-no-windows-hosts-mgt=false

======= DOCKER info =========
docker location: lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  staff  54 Jan  3  2023 /usr/local/bin/docker -> /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker
Docker Desktop Version: Docker Desktop for Mac 4.16.2 build 95914
docker version: 
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.29
 Version:           20.10.22
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.18.9
 Git commit:        3a2c30b
 Built:             Thu Dec 15 22:28:41 2022
 OS/Arch:           darwin/arm64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Desktop 4.16.2 (95914)
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.22
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.18.9
  Git commit:       42c8b31
  Built:            Thu Dec 15 22:25:43 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.14
  GitCommit:        9ba4b250366a5ddde94bb7c9d1def331423aa323
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.4
  GitCommit:        v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=notset
======= Mutagen Info =========
Mutagen is installed in ddev, version=0.16.0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name: lilp-d7
Identifier: sync_3jTGajnGIFbyWxdjcIfkuCTPA4UNBaggwiCC0NUKoyM
Labels:
    com.ddev.volume-signature: var-run-1682983627
Configuration:
    Synchronization mode: Two Way Resolved
    Maximum allowed entry count: Default (2⁶⁴−1)
    Maximum staging file size: Default (18 EB)
    Symbolic link mode: POSIX Raw
    Ignore VCS mode: Default (Propagate)
    Ignores:
        /.git
        /.tarballs
        /.ddev/db_snapshots
        /.ddev/.importdb*
        .DS_Store
        .idea
        /docroot/sites/default/files
    Permissions mode: Default (Portable)
Alpha:
    URL: /Users/me/Sites/lilp-d7
    Configuration:
        Watch mode: Default (Portable)
        Watch polling interval: Default (10 seconds)
        Probe mode: Default (Probe)
        Scan mode: Default (Accelerated)
        Stage mode: Neighboring
        File mode: Default (0600)
        Directory mode: Default (0700)
        Default file/directory owner: Default
        Default file/directory group: Default
    Connected: No
Beta:
    URL: docker://ddev-lilp-d7-web/var/www/html
        DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    Configuration:
        Watch mode: Default (Portable)
        Watch polling interval: Default (10 seconds)
        Probe mode: Default (Probe)
        Scan mode: Default (Accelerated)
        Stage mode: Neighboring
        File mode: Default (0600)
        Directory mode: Default (0700)
        Default file/directory owner: Default
        Default file/directory group: Default
    Connected: No
Status: [Paused]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name: bps
Identifier: sync_KwMStSYDpTM3LuSBMp30KiUODTqZDgFNsenS5ybW9CZ
Labels:
    com.ddev.volume-signature: var-run-1683225466
Configuration:
    Synchronization mode: Two Way Resolved
    Maximum allowed entry count: Default (2⁶⁴−1)
    Maximum staging file size: Default (18 EB)
    Symbolic link mode: POSIX Raw
    Ignore VCS mode: Default (Propagate)
    Ignores:
        /.git
        /.tarballs
        /.ddev/db_snapshots
        /.ddev/.importdb*
        .DS_Store
        .idea
        /web/sites/default/files
    Permissions mode: Default (Portable)
Alpha:
    URL: /Users/me/Sites/bps
    Configuration:
        Watch mode: Default (Portable)
        Watch polling interval: Default (10 seconds)
        Probe mode: Default (Probe)
        Scan mode: Default (Accelerated)
        Stage mode: Neighboring
        File mode: Default (0600)
        Directory mode: Default (0700)
        Default file/directory owner: Default
        Default file/directory group: Default
    Connected: Yes
Beta:
    URL: docker://ddev-bps-web/var/www/html
        DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    Configuration:
        Watch mode: Default (Portable)
        Watch polling interval: Default (10 seconds)
        Probe mode: Default (Probe)
        Scan mode: Default (Accelerated)
        Stage mode: Neighboring
        File mode: Default (0600)
        Directory mode: Default (0700)
        Default file/directory owner: Default
        Default file/directory group: Default
    Connected: No
Status: Connecting to beta
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name: sandbox-d10
Identifier: sync_e8bNISc1Ym2MBRNoVz4hQKqBVnY5JXX8lv1ExgFdcb5
Labels:
    com.ddev.volume-signature: var-run-1683311900
Configuration:
    Synchronization mode: Two Way Resolved
    Maximum allowed entry count: Default (2⁶⁴−1)
    Maximum staging file size: Default (18 EB)
    Symbolic link mode: POSIX Raw
    Ignore VCS mode: Default (Propagate)
    Ignores:
        /.git
        /.tarballs
        /.ddev/db_snapshots
        /.ddev/.importdb*
        .DS_Store
        .idea
        /web/sites/default/files
    Permissions mode: Default (Portable)
Alpha:
    URL: /Users/me/Sites/sandbox-d10
    Configuration:
        Watch mode: Default (Portable)
        Watch polling interval: Default (10 seconds)
        Probe mode: Default (Probe)
        Scan mode: Default (Accelerated)
        Stage mode: Neighboring
        File mode: Default (0600)
        Directory mode: Default (0700)
        Default file/directory owner: Default
        Default file/directory group: Default
    Connected: No
Beta:
    URL: docker://ddev-sandbox-d10-web/var/www/html
        DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    Configuration:
        Watch mode: Default (Portable)
        Watch polling interval: Default (10 seconds)
        Probe mode: Default (Probe)
        Scan mode: Default (Accelerated)
        Stage mode: Neighboring
        File mode: Default (0600)
        Directory mode: Default (0700)
        Default file/directory owner: Default
        Default file/directory group: Default
    Connected: No
Status: [Paused]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name: sctcc
Identifier: sync_XFp7fm9y7aIGSAs3AJlUifxpYzXpepPSY6AUAVM5A1g
Labels:
    com.ddev.volume-signature: var-run-1686310934
Configuration:
    Synchronization mode: Two Way Resolved
    Maximum allowed entry count: Default (2⁶⁴−1)
    Maximum staging file size: Default (18 EB)
    Symbolic link mode: POSIX Raw
    Ignore VCS mode: Default (Propagate)
    Ignores:
        /.git
        /.tarballs
        /.ddev/db_snapshots
        /.ddev/.importdb*
        .DS_Store
        .idea
        /web/sites/default/files
    Permissions mode: Default (Portable)
Alpha:
    URL: /Users/me/Sites/sctcc
    Configuration:
        Watch mode: Default (Portable)
        Watch polling interval: Default (10 seconds)
        Probe mode: Default (Probe)
        Scan mode: Default (Accelerated)
        Stage mode: Neighboring
        File mode: Default (0600)
        Directory mode: Default (0700)
        Default file/directory owner: Default
        Default file/directory group: Default
    Connected: Yes
    Synchronizable contents:
        10354 directories
        41815 files (896 MB)
        5 symbolic links
Beta:
    URL: docker://ddev-sctcc-web/var/www/html
        DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    Configuration:
        Watch mode: Default (Portable)
        Watch polling interval: Default (10 seconds)
        Probe mode: Default (Probe)
        Scan mode: Default (Accelerated)
        Stage mode: Neighboring
        File mode: Default (0600)
        Directory mode: Default (0700)
        Default file/directory owner: Default
        Default file/directory group: Default
    Connected: Yes
    Synchronizable contents:
        10354 directories
        41815 files (896 MB)
        5 symbolic links
Status: Watching for changes
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name: oul
Identifier: sync_O3BmaaKjS1UT3JYwzIdTLXLYHAUEajGyRWlbnKyZ8Cz
Labels:
    com.ddev.volume-signature: var-run-1689009735
Configuration:
    Synchronization mode: Two Way Resolved
    Maximum allowed entry count: Default (2⁶⁴−1)
    Maximum staging file size: Default (18 EB)
    Symbolic link mode: POSIX Raw
    Ignore VCS mode: Default (Propagate)
    Ignores:
        /.git
        /.tarballs
        /.ddev/db_snapshots
        /.ddev/.importdb*
        .DS_Store
        .idea
        /web/sites/default/files
    Permissions mode: Default (Portable)
Alpha:
    URL: /Users/me/Sites/oul
    Configuration:
        Watch mode: Default (Portable)
        Watch polling interval: Default (10 seconds)
        Probe mode: Default (Probe)
        Scan mode: Default (Accelerated)
        Stage mode: Neighboring
        File mode: Default (0600)
        Directory mode: Default (0700)
        Default file/directory owner: Default
        Default file/directory group: Default
    Connected: Yes
    Synchronizable contents:
        10493 directories
        43010 files (290 MB)
        6 symbolic links
Beta:
    URL: docker://ddev-oul-web/var/www/html
        DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    Configuration:
        Watch mode: Default (Portable)
        Watch polling interval: Default (10 seconds)
        Probe mode: Default (Probe)
        Scan mode: Default (Accelerated)
        Stage mode: Neighboring
        File mode: Default (0600)
        Directory mode: Default (0700)
        Default file/directory owner: Default
        Default file/directory group: Default
    Connected: Yes
    Synchronizable contents:
        10493 directories
        43010 files (290 MB)
        6 symbolic links
Status: Watching for changes
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
======= Docker Info =========
Docker platform: docker-desktop 
Using docker context: default (unix:///var/run/docker.sock) 
docker-compose: v2.15.1 
Using DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock 
Docker version: 20.10.22 
Able to run simple container that mounts a volume. 
Able to use internet inside container. 
Docker disk space:
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
overlay                  95.0G     53.9G     36.2G  60% /

unable to create project at project root '/Users/me/Sites/lilp-d7': project root /Users/me/Sites/lilp-d7 does not exist
unable to create project at project root '/Users/me/Sites/sandbox-d10': project root /Users/me/Sites/sandbox-d10 does not exist
Container ddev-bmc-dba  Removed
Container ddev-bmc-db  Removed
Container ddev-bmc-web  Removed
Network ddev-bmc_default  Removed
Project bmc has been stopped.
Container ddev-bps-db  Removed
Container ddev-bps-dba  Removed
Container ddev-bps-web  Removed
Network ddev-bps_default  Removed
Project bps has been stopped.
Container ddev-lilpd7-dba  Removed
Container ddev-lilpd7-solr-1  Removed
Container ddev-lilpd7-db  Removed
Container ddev-lilpd7-web  Removed
Network ddev-lilpd7_default  Removed
Project lilpd7 has been stopped.
Container ddev-oul-dba  Removed
Container ddev-oul-db  Removed
Container ddev-oul-web  Removed
Network ddev-oul_default  Removed
Project ou-law has been stopped.
Container ddev-qcc-db  Removed
Container ddev-qcc-dba  Removed
Container ddev-qcc-web  Removed
Network ddev-qcc_default  Removed
Project qcc has been stopped.
Container ddev-qccd7-dba  Removed
Container ddev-qccd7-db  Removed
Container ddev-qccd7-web  Removed
Network ddev-qccd7_default  Removed
Project qccd7 has been stopped.
Container ddev-ru-map-db  Removed
Container ddev-ru-map-dba  Removed
Container ddev-ru-map-web  Removed
Network ddev-ru-map_default  Removed
Project rutgers-map has been stopped.
Container ddev-sandbox-web  Removed
Container ddev-sandbox-db  Removed
Container ddev-sandbox-dba  Removed
Network ddev-sandbox_default  Removed
Project sandbox has been stopped.
Container ddev-sctcc-db  Removed
Container ddev-sctcc-dba  Removed
Container ddev-sctcc-web  Removed
Network ddev-sctcc_default  Removed
Project sctcc has been stopped.
Stopped mutagen daemon
The ddev-ssh-agent container has been removed. When you start it again you will have to use 'ddev auth ssh' to provide key authentication again.
Existing docker containers: 
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS                     PORTS                                                                       NAMES
9b5121dd23a9   bitnami/mysql:5.7.29-debian-10-r51   "/lando-entrypoint.s…"   5 weeks ago   Exited (255) 5 weeks ago   127.0.0.1:3308->3306/tcp                                                    bmcd9_d7_database_1
7a7d378cf304   phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:5.1.1          "/lando-entrypoint.s…"   5 weeks ago   Exited (255) 5 weeks ago   127.0.0.1:32821->80/tcp                                                     bmcd9_phpmyadmin_1
bb7fa56fd1a9   bitnami/mysql:5.7.29-debian-10-r51   "/lando-entrypoint.s…"   5 weeks ago   Exited (255) 5 weeks ago   127.0.0.1:3307->3306/tcp                                                    bmcd9_database_1
35ba47d636d8   mailhog/mailhog:v1.0.1               "/lando-entrypoint.s…"   5 weeks ago   Exited (255) 5 weeks ago   1025/tcp, 8025/tcp, 127.0.0.1:32818->80/tcp                                 bmcd9_mailhog_1
46c222da5edf   devwithlando/php:8.1-apache-4        "/lando-entrypoint.s…"   5 weeks ago   Exited (255) 5 weeks ago   127.0.0.1:32820->80/tcp, 127.0.0.1:32819->443/tcp                           bmcd9_appserver_1
091c874622ba   traefik:2.2.0                        "/lando-entrypoint.s…"   5 weeks ago   Exited (255) 5 weeks ago   127.0.0.1:8000->80/tcp, 127.0.0.1:444->443/tcp, 127.0.0.1:32811->8080/tcp   landoproxyhyperion5000gandalfedition_proxy_1
Creating a new ddev project config in the current directory (/Users/me/Sites/tryddevproject-12561) 
Once completed, your configuration will be written to /Users/me/Sites/tryddevproject-12561/.ddev/config.yaml
 
Configuring unrecognized codebase as project type 'php' at /Users/me/Sites/tryddevproject-12561/web 
Configuration complete. You may now run 'ddev start'. 
Network ddev_default created 
Starting tryddevproject-12561... 
Container ddev-ssh-agent  Started 
ssh-agent container is running: If you want to add authentication to the ssh-agent container, run 'ddev auth ssh' to enable your keys. 
Network ddev-tryddevproject-12561_default  Created 
Container ddev-tryddevproject-12561-dba  Started 
Container ddev-tryddevproject-12561-db  Started 
Container ddev-tryddevproject-12561-web  Started 
Container ddev-router  Started 
Successfully started tryddevproject-12561 
Project can be reached at https://tryddevproject-12561.ddev.site https://127.0.0.1:54506 
======== Curl of site from inside container:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 27 Jul 2023 14:30:50 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding

======== curl -I of http://tryddevproject-12561.ddev.site from outside:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.20.1
Date: Thu, 27 Jul 2023 14:30:51 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding

======== full curl of http://tryddevproject-12561.ddev.site from outside:
Success accessing database... db via TCP/IP
ddev is working. You will want to delete this project with 'ddev delete -Oy tryddevproject-12561'
======== Project ownership on host:
drwxr-xr-x  4 me  staff  128 Jul 27 10:30 ../tryddevproject-12561
======== Project ownership in container:
drwxr-xr-x 4 me dialout 128 Jul 27 14:30 /var/www/html
======== In-container filesystem:
Filesystem     Type          1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
grpcfuse       fuse.grpcfuse 971350180 337748772 633601408  35% /var/www/html
======== curl again of tryddevproject-12561 from host:
Success accessing database... db via TCP/IP
ddev is working. You will want to delete this project with 'ddev delete -Oy tryddevproject-12561'
```

=== ADDING OUTPUT FROM DRUPAL 10 QUICKSTART ===

```
% mkdir sandbox
% cd sandbox 
% ddev config --project-type=drupal10 --docroot=web --create-docroot
Creating a new ddev project config in the current directory (/Users/me/Sites/sandbox) 
Once completed, your configuration will be written to /Users/me/Sites/sandbox/.ddev/config.yaml
 
Created docroot at /Users/me/Sites/sandbox/web 
You have specified a project type of drupal10 but no project of that type is found in /Users/me/Sites/sandbox/web 
No settings.php file exists, creating one 
Configuration complete. You may now run 'ddev start'. 
me@Jeffs-MacBook-Pro sandbox % ddev start
Starting sandbox... 
Network ddev-sandbox_default  Created 
Container ddev-sandbox-dba  Started 
Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/Users/me/Sites/sandbox/.ddev': mkdir /host_mnt/Users/me/Sites/sandbox/.ddev: no such file or directory 
Failed to start sandbox: ComposeCmd failed to run 'COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=ddev-sandbox docker-compose -f /Users/me/Sites/sandbox/.ddev/.ddev-docker-compose-full.yaml up --build -d', action='[up --build -d]', err='exit status 1', stdout='#1 [drud/ddev-dbserver-mariadb-10.4:v1.21.5-sandbox-built internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 transferring dockerfile: 612B 0.0s done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [drud/ddev-dbserver-mariadb-10.4:v1.21.5-sandbox-built internal] load .dockerignore
#2 transferring context: 0.0s
#2 transferring context: 2B 0.0s done
#2 DONE 0.0s

#3 [drud/ddev-webserver:v1.21.5-sandbox-built internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#3 transferring dockerfile: 976B done
#3 DONE 0.0s

#4 [drud/ddev-webserver:v1.21.5-sandbox-built internal] load .dockerignore
#4 transferring context: 2B done
#4 DONE 0.0s

#5 [drud/ddev-dbserver-mariadb-10.4:v1.21.5-sandbox-built internal] load metadata for docker.io/drud/ddev-dbserver-mariadb-10.4:v1.21.5
#5 DONE 0.0s

#6 [drud/ddev-webserver:v1.21.5-sandbox-built internal] load metadata for docker.io/drud/ddev-webserver:v1.21.5
#6 DONE 0.0s

#7 [drud/ddev-webserver:v1.21.5-sandbox-built 1/4] FROM docker.io/drud/ddev-webserver:v1.21.5
#7 DONE 0.0s

#8 [drud/ddev-webserver:v1.21.5-sandbox-built 2/4] RUN (groupadd --gid 20 "me" || groupadd "me" || true) && (useradd  -l -m -s "/bin/bash" --gid "me" --comment '' --uid 501 "me" || useradd  -l -m -s "/bin/bash" --gid "me" --comment '' "me" || useradd  -l -m -s "/bin/bash" --gid "20" --comment '' "me" || useradd -l -m -s "/bin/bash" --comment '' me )
#8 CACHED

#9 [drud/ddev-webserver:v1.21.5-sandbox-built 3/4] RUN export XDEBUG_MODE=off; composer self-update --stable || composer self-update --stable || true; composer self-update --2 || composer self-update --2 || true
#9 CACHED

#10 [drud/ddev-webserver:v1.21.5-sandbox-built 4/4] RUN mkdir -p /home/me && chown me /home/me && chmod 600 /home/me/.pgpass
#10 CACHED

#11 [drud/ddev-dbserver-mariadb-10.4:v1.21.5-sandbox-built 1/2] FROM docker.io/drud/ddev-dbserver-mariadb-10.4:v1.21.5
#11 DONE 0.0s

#12 [drud/ddev-dbserver-mariadb-10.4:v1.21.5-sandbox-built 2/2] RUN (groupadd --gid 20 "me" || groupadd "me" || true) && (useradd  -l -m -s "/bin/bash" --gid "me" --comment '' --uid 501 "me" || useradd  -l -m -s "/bin/bash" --gid "me" --comment '' "me" || useradd  -l -m -s "/bin/bash" --gid "20" --comment '' "me" || useradd -l -m -s "/bin/bash" --comment '' me )
#12 CACHED

#13 [drud/ddev-webserver:v1.21.5-sandbox-built] exporting to image
#13 exporting layers done
#13 writing image sha256:e0d9492258d3962e4106d43dc4feaed348beb313554d301306a3b63cb9a62809 done
#13 naming to docker.io/drud/ddev-dbserver-mariadb-10.4:v1.21.5-sandbox-built done
#13 writing image sha256:0cbebcfd096fe2fb424d18a06bc0ae2fb1eb6e4b7d5e974eb96cb7487bfb5716 done
#13 naming to docker.io/drud/ddev-webserver:v1.21.5-sandbox-built done
#13 DONE 0.0s
', stderr='Network ddev-sandbox_default  Creating
Network ddev-sandbox_default  Created
Container ddev-sandbox-web  Creating
Container ddev-sandbox-dba  Creating
Container ddev-sandbox-db  Creating
Container ddev-sandbox-dba  Created
Container ddev-sandbox-db  Created
Container ddev-sandbox-web  Created
Container ddev-sandbox-web  Starting
Container ddev-sandbox-db  Starting
Container ddev-sandbox-dba  Starting
Container ddev-sandbox-dba  Started
Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/Users/me/Sites/sandbox/.ddev': mkdir /host_mnt/Users/me/Sites/sandbox/.ddev: no such file or directory'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Docker provider isn't properly mounting the project.

`Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/Users/me/Sites/sandbox/.ddev': mkdir /host_mnt/Users/me/Sites/sandbox/.ddev: no such file or directory'`

Are your other projects, in the same `Sites` directory working fine?

It looks like it's trying to mount /host_mnt/Users/me/Sites/sandbox instead of /Users/me/Sites/sandbox, which is odd.

You don't mention what Docker Provider you're using, which matters.

I recommend that you create a plain vanilla Drupal 10 project using the instructions at https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/quickstart/#drupal and see how that works, then come back to the Pantheon checkout.

It may work better to help you if you come over to Discord at https://discord.gg/hCZFfAMc5k or create an issue in the [DDEV Issue Queue](https://github.com/ddev/ddev/issues) - in either case, please do a `ddev debug test` and provide the full output of that command.

Comment: Are you perhaps using a very old version of Docker Desktop, or perhaps not using the standard filesystem type, maybe you're using the `osxfs` mount type? I haven't seen that `/host_mnt` in a few years, but maybe it happens if you're using the alternate mount type on Docker Desktop. Please use the standard mount type, Virtiofs with latest, or the more recent "gRPC Fuse".

Comment: I've added the output from ddev debug test, which seemed to work fine, to the description, and the output from following the quickstart for Drupal 10, which did not. [btw, nice to chat with you rfay...it's been years!]

Comment: Also, the error does NOT occur when doing the Drupal 9 quickstart (just did one).

Comment: I can't imagine that there would be a difference between Drupal9 and drupal10 quickstarts if done in sibling directories (same parent directory). Please try that again. That would make no sense at all. But you may want to delete any docker volumes that relate to either one? Use new names for each of them. Like `drupal9new` and `drupal10new` or something. There really isn't any difference between the two.

Comment: Great to chat with you too! Feel free to join us in the DDEV discord at https://discord.gg/hCZFfAMc5k